# Vue 3 Unit Test Error - "Cannot find module '@jest/globals'

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm pretty new to Vue and also new to Unit Testing. I'm trying to setup my first unit test in my Vue 3 project and I get this error when I try to run the test:

```
Cannot find module '@jest/globals
```

This occurs in my test spec as soon as I try:

```
jest.mock("@services/myService.service");
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "vue-myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primevue": "^3.5.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.14",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

Are there any packages here that need updating to get this to work?  Is it the Jest version (24.0.19) that is perhaps the cause of this?  Or the version of vue-jest maybe? I've seen another answer somewhere else to a similar question talking about the versions of babel-jest but that does not seem to be in my project? (should it be?)

Many thanks if anyone can help!

Comment: Did you try to delete node-modules and package.lock.json and run npm install again? Solves most of these problems.

Comment: Hi - I haven't tried that, no.  I may well try it if nobody comes up with any other suggestions! - thanks

Comment: re-running npm install made no difference

Comment: Also deleted the lock file?

Comment: Yeah I did that